# Is it safe to send html emails without any header elements (h1, h2, h3, h4)

Tags: html-email

I'm finding it very hard to style multiple header elements (h1, h2, h3) with or without links. My html email has headers with multiple colors and styles and hotmail and outlook 2010 behave very badly with them. I was wondering if it is safe to use 'p' elements for titles, where I can have more control. Will the email have a negative or spam effect in any email client/provider?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It may slightly increase your spam score to use a large font in a `<p>` tag.  Unusually large text in the message body is a commonly used trigger for spam filters.

- A general rule of thumb is to not use a font size greater than ~3 (~12 pt) in a `<p>` tag, to minimize spam filtering.
- Using header tags for unusually large fonts is a safer alternative and is less likely to increase your spam score.
- Using images for large header text is another alternative to minimize spam filtering.

Here's a good overview on [how to avoid spam filters](http://www.dotmailer.co.uk/email_marketing_resources/deliverability/getting_your_email_past_the_spam_filters.aspx).

**Example:**

Here is an [example header](http://www.digilink.net/antispam-ex.shtml) that illustrates the spam filter algorithm used by DigiLink's SpamAssassin tool.  In this example, declaring a font size of 3 and up adds 0.3 to the risk scoring, where total scores of 4 and greater are marked as spam. In this example, using an h1 header with the default font sizing would not trigger the score increase.

Comment: Unfortunately the link on "how to avoid spam filters" is down.

Answer (score 3):

I really do not believe that using p tags as a replacement of header tags can cause any negative effects on email clients. How did you apply style to those elements? That can be the origin of your problems.

To avoid any issues, I have used some of the advice presented on the following links: [Getting Started with HTML Emails](https://web.archive.org/web/20140828084630/https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-html-emails--net-17200), [20 Email Design Best Practices](https://web.archive.org/web/20140301190701/http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/20-email-design-best-practices-and-resources-for-beginners--net-7309)

Answer (score -5):

When you're structuring the HTML coding for a Web page, it can look a little like an outline, with main headings and subheadings. For best SEO results, it is important to place keywords in those headings, within Heading tags.

Heading tags are part of the HTML coding for a Web page. Headings are defined with H1 to H6 tags. The H1 tag defines the most important heading on the page (usually the largest or boldest, too), whereas H6 indicates the lowest-level heading. You want to avoid thinking of headings as simply formatting for your pages: Headings carry a lot of weight with the search engines because they're for categorization, not cosmetics. You can control what each heading looks like consistently through your site using a CSS style sheet that specifies the font, size, color, and other attributes for each Heading tag. Here's an example of what various heading tags can look like:

```
<H1>This is a heading</H1>
<H2>This is subheading A</H2>
<H2>This is subheading B</H2>
<H3>This is a lower subheading</H3>
```

Search engines pay special attention to the words in your headings because they expect headings to include clues to the page’s main topics. You definitely want to include the page’s keywords inside Heading tags.

Comment: he was talking about html in emails and not webpages